# How do i take an array list position and turn that into a string?

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Hopefully this will be an easy answer and i'm just overlooking something minor.

Goal: take an array list (which currently contains lines of text from a text file) and set a `String` variable equal a specified array list position. 
At the moment, each line is raw text taken from an Encyclopedia file. I need to be able to remove non alpha's via the .replaceAll function. However, my current program returns a null pointer exception and I'm having some trouble  understanding why. I'm fairly new to Java so full answers and explanations are much appreciated.

my code: (My teacher told us to use EasyReader class to make our lives, well easier...)

```
EasyReader fileIn = new EasyReader("Encyclopedia.txt"); 
public void createList()
    {
        String x=fileIn.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while((!fileIn.eof()))
        {
            String y=fileIn.readLine();
            list.add(y);
        }
        int count=0;
        while(count<list.size())
        {
            String temp=list.get(count);
            temp.replaceAll("[^a-zA-z ]", ""); //null pointer points to this line
            temp.toLowerCase();                //and this line
            list.set(count, temp);
            count++;
        }
        count=0;
        while(count<list.size());
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(count));
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(list.size());
        while(count<list.size())
        {
            fileOut.println(list.get(count));
            count++;
        }
        fileOut.close();
}
```

thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: What's the count when it fails? Are there few enough lines so you can print each one as you read it, to debug? It looks like one of those y's is null; maybe the last one? Unrelated, but String is immutable, so its methods return a new string -- they don't modify the current one. That means you need to do `temp = temp.replace all...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your error!

Your while loop should go only to `list.size() - 1` not the `list.size()` you have there. See below:

```
 while(count<list.size()- 1)
    {
         String temp=list.get(count);
         temp.replaceAll("[^a-zA-z ]", ""); //null pointer points to this line
         temp.toLowerCase();                //and this line
         list.set(count, temp);
         count++;
    }
```

Comment: I think this will work for now. Thank you very much for the help. I always had the feeling it was something small i overlooked... :)

Comment: While this may work, please do _not_ conclude that your iteration over the list was wrong. It was right. For instance, if the list has 4 elements, the last value of `count` that satisfies `while (count < list.size())` is 3, which is exactly what it should be. In fact, if you _had_ gone past the edge of the list, you wouldn't have gotten a `null` back -- you'd have gotten an IndexOutOfBoundException. The reason you got a null wasn't because of how you iterated over the list, but because the last element you put in was null. The bug was in the last iteration of the `while (fileIn.eof())` loop.

Comment: And to round that off -- if you conclude from this that the right way to loop over a list is to do `while (count < list.size() - 1)`, then all your loops will omit the last element, which is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the two lines that you commented with this instead:

```
temp = temp.replaceAll("[^a-zA-z ]", ""); 
temp = temp.toLowerCase();
```

This is because the `replaceAll()` method does not change the original string itself, but rather returns a new string with the characters replaced. Same thing with `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: I tried this. This is actually what i had originally. Compiled, executed, and still receiving null pointer on those lines. :/

Comment: I feel like it's a problem with how i'm talking to the array list as if i print out (temp), I am met with the properly formatted strings in console... thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You made two mistakes:

1) the `replaceAll` regex should be `temp.replaceAll("[^a-zA-z]", "")` (no space after z)

2) you can combine two lines into one method `temp.replaceAll("[^a-zA-z]", "").toLowerCase()`

3) you need to save your newly returned String to the original variable temp:

```
temp = temp.replaceAll("[^a-zA-z]", "").toLowerCase();
```

as @Suitangi mentioned, `replaceAll()` method does not change the original string itself, but rather returns a new string with the characters replaced. Same thing with `toLowerCase()`.

Hope that helps.

EDIT:
In the last iteration `String temp = null;`
Add `if` condition to check it, before regex:

```
if (temp!=null){
    temp = temp.replaceAll("[^a-zA-z]", "").toLowerCase();
    list.set(count, temp);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: I need the space after z because the strings i'm collecting are a bunch of words and removing white spaces turns it into just a string of characters. I tried the other two edits, and am still getting a null pointer exception :/

Comment: I also tested without the space (just to be sure) and was still met with the null pointer exc